# Passing and updating prop / state values from parent with multiple components in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state-management, react-state

I have two components, a select list with several options in one component and a button in another component.

What I would like to in the UI is that you can select any option from the select list and also that you can click the button to reset the select list back to 'select'.

Both of these components are inside the Parent component which is what is rendered - I am trying to keep the parent as the 'single source of truth' so that the select list can update its value when selected and then the reset button can also update this same value.

I've written how I think this should work but the select list is stuck on the first item and the reset button doesn't update the list, can't spot where I've gone wrong, if anyone can give me some advice / point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful - thanks

```
class SelectList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onSelectListChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const selectedValue = this.props.selectedValue;
    return (
      <select value={selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value='One'>One</option>
        <option value='select'>select</option>
        <option value='Three'>Three</option>
        <option value='Four'>Four</option>
        <option value='Five'>Five</option>
      </select>
    );
  }
}

class SelectListReset extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onSelectListChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Reset list to select</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSelectedListChange = this.handleSelectedListChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelectedListChange(selectedValue) {
    this.setState({selectedValue});
  }

  handleResetChange(selectedValue) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: 'select'});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectList
          onSelectListChange={this.handleSelectedListChange}
          selectedValue={this.handleSelectedListChange}
        />
        <SelectListReset 
          handleResetChange={this.handleSelectedListChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In parent component,  you are passing `handleResetChange`  prop to `SelectListReset` but executing `this.props.onSelectListChange`. Also function handle click should be named as e.g. `handleClick` instead of `handleChange`.

Answer (score 0):

You are going wrong in your **parent component**, the way you are passing the `selectedValue` down to **SelectList** and also the way the **State** is set, I have edited the code please check

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      selectedValue: 'select'
    }
    this.handleSelectedListChange = this.handleSelectedListChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelectedListChange(selectedValue) {
    this.setState({selectedValue});
  }

  handleResetChange(selectedValue) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: 'select'});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectList
          onSelectListChange={this.handleSelectedListChange}
          selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
        />
        <SelectListReset 
          handleResetChange={this.handleSelectedListChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
javascript
```